# Calcular velocidade media dos últimos registros da tabela MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

estou desenvolvendo um projeto que calcular a evolução da subida   d´água . Feito com arduino e sensor ultrasonic ele alimenta os dados em uma tabela mysql . a cada 60 segundos ele insere o valor da altura da água.Até aqui tudo certo.

Como poderia extrair os dois últimos registros e reportar a velocidade media em uma saída com php ?

Muito Obrigado

Answer (score 2):

Como não sei o andamento do projeto, irei supor que você ainda não desenvolveu a parte de conexão do banco de dados.

Para utilizar o **[MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg)** com o **[PHP](http://php.net)**, é necessário utilizar a extensão **[PDO](http://br.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.pdo.php)** ou **[MySQLi](http://br.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.quickstart.php)**.
*Nesse exemplo utilizarei o MySQLi.*

```
// Aqui abrimos uma conexão com o banco de dados
$db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "123456", "teste");

// Aqui nós utilizamos a função AVG para obter a média dos valores
$result = $db->query("SELECT AVG(`nivel`) AS media FROM (SELECT m.`nivel` FROM nivel_agua m ORDER BY m.id DESC LIMIT 2) nivel_agua;");

// Exibimos o resultado
echo "Media: " . $result->fetch_assoc()["media"];

// Fechamos a conexão
$result->close();
$db->close();
```

**Estrutura do tabela que utilizei para teste**

```
+-------+-----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type      | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+-----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| nivel | float     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| data  | timestamp | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+-----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: Isso mesmo !!!! Rapaz .. funcionou !! brigado pelo atenção... !